# MS access query group dates to start date and end date range

Tags: ms-access

I have table for permission

| ID | UserID | Date | Permission |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1370 | 2022/10/24 | Approved |
| 2 | 1370 | 2022/10/31 | Rejected |
| 3 | 1370 | 2022/11/07 | Approved |
| 4 | 1370 | 2022/11/14 | Approved |
| 5 | 1370 | 2022/11/21 | Rejected |
| 6 | 1370 | 2022/11/28 | Rejected |
| 7 | 1370 | 2022/12/05 | Rejected |
| 8 | 1370 | 2022/12/12 | Approved |
| 9 | 1370 | 2022/12/19 | Approved |
| 10 | 1370 | 2022/12/26 | Approved |
| 11 | 1370 | 2023/01/02 | Rejected |
| 12 | 2456 | 2022/12/26 | Rejected |
| 13 | 2456 | 2023/01/02 | Rejected |
| 14 | 2456 | 2023/01/09 | Approved |
| 15 | 2456 | 2023/01/16 | Approved |

I want select query to group dates based on start date and end date

result query like this:

| UserID | Date From | Date Till | Permission |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1370 | 2022/10/24 | 2022/10/24 | Approved |
| 1370 | 2022/10/31 | 2022/10/31 | Rejected |
| 1370 | 2022/11/07 | 2022/11/14 | Approved |
| 1370 | 2022/11/21 | 2022/12/05 | Rejected |
| 1370 | 2022/12/12 | 2022/12/26 | Approved |
| 1370 | 2023/01/02 | 2023/01/02 | Rejected |
| 2456 | 2022/12/26 | 2023/01/02 | Rejected |
| 2456 | 2023/01/09 | 2023/01/16 | Approved |

**EDIT:**

this is a part of my table for userID = 1370 and 2456. users request for permission and system approve or reject their request. each day can reject or approved. so when i want to response their request , either get them result of all 365 days of year separately , or group rows with start and end date period. –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it by user Defined(udf) function in vba.

```
Function partID(userID, rowID)
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("select * from permission where userID = " & userID & " order by permission.date")
    
    i = 0
    p = ""
    
    Do While rst.EOF = False
        If p <> rst("permission") Then
            i = i + 1
            p = rst("permission")
        End If
        If rowID = rst("ID") Then
            Exit Do
        End If
        rst.MoveNext
    Loop
    partID = i

End Function
```

then select query and group it.

```
SELECT UserID, Min(Date) AS DateFrom, Max(Date) AS DateTill, Permission
FROM Permission
GROUP BY UserID, Permission, partid([userid],[id])
ORDER BY UserID, partid([userid],[id]);
```

and it works... :D

Answer (score -1):

It's a little unclear what corolation there is between these date? (Relationship)
im guessing that these are related somehow ie a Job number of sorts??? (U need to clarify) Ie ID 3+4 in the 1st Tbl???
And im guessing that if there is a Relationship you would need to show/add that to your Qry IE Table with dates, another with Job ref
And also, im guessing, if there is a from date and a null till date then Till date = From date?

Comment: Please post questions and remarks as a _comment_.

Comment: @AryaBasiri: Please move this comment to your _question_ for others to better understand.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).